# Bootstrap 3 : two button on a row

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, typescript

I am using bootstrap 3 and have a my data coming from a service. I am using ng-repeat to render the design,I need two buttons to appear in one row and if we are using mobile then one button in a row. The Buttons should be center on the screen as indicated below.

```
                          Button Text 1         Button Text 2
                          Button Tex 3          Button Text 4
```

This is my html code

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-offset-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Here sits text 1</button></div>  
      <div class="col-sm-4"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Here sits text 2</button></div>    
   </div>   
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-offset-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Here sits text 3</button></div>  
      <div class="col-sm-4"> 
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" style="word-wrap: break-word;">Here sits text 4 </button></div>    
   </div> 

</div>
```

How would I avoid using multiple rows in order to force two columns?

I am asking for that to make my ng-repeat just render some columns because, it would not work with this design?

**Update For Question:**

I have updated using the answer suggested below, its working now:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-offset-2  col-sm-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2   col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="text-align:center;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Button text 1</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="text-align:center;">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Button text 2</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-offset-2  col-sm-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2  col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="text-align:center;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Button text 1</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="text-align:center;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Button text 4</button>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Is it possible to use the same styling for cols and and make it work (there are offsets on alternate cols.

Comment: can you put it in fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thinkyou should take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/2zu0oksc/

You can have a `div` with class `row` and many `col-*`

Setting the `col-xs-12` to the div, you are saying taht in small devices it will take all the row width.

This is the code:

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="text-align:center;">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button text 1</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="text-align:center;">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button text 2</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="text-align:center;">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button text 3</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="text-align:center;">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button text 4</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. However the space  between the buttons when rendered in one row next to each others is big. How I can decrease that spacing and make sure they are also centered in a row?

Answer (score 0):

```
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
      <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-4">
         <button class="btn btn-primary">
      Text 1
         </button>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">
       Text 1
      </button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
     <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-4">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">
      Text 1
         </button>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1">
          <button class="btn btn-primary">
           Text 1
         </button>
       </div>
   </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wuy235f9/

This works but you'll have to adjust the offset and col size you want for it!